# Is there something wrong with my Bayesian hierarchical spatio-temporal model?

Tags: bayesian, gibbs, spatio-temporal, bugs

I built a Bayesian spatio-temporal model and one of the parameters to be estimated is the random spatial effects s. The random spatial effect is assigned an intrinsic conditional autoregressive prior (ICAR). 
Using Gibbs sampling via winBUGS software, I ran and discarded 20,000 iterations as burn-in and did a further 10,000 iterations with a thinning factor of 5. The trace plots for all other parameters in the model were fine (standard fuzzy caterpillar look) and I visually inspected convergence using the Gelman Rubin diagnostic plot. Autocorrelation was also minimal for these parameters. However, for the variance of the random spatial effect, sigma_s, I got a result I am not accustomed with. Since the trace plot shows an apparent convergence to 0, I assume that this parameter is estimated at 0, although I am not sure why it does not have the fuzzy caterpillar look (does this have to do with the constraint that the variance must be positive?).
Any explanation as to why this result is occurring will be very helpful.

[image]